# tesseract-orc not reading text from even simple images

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

For the sake of others finding this in Google, I'll explain my question in detail though it should be obvious. I'm using tesseract-ocr with the hope of removing text from images. The problem I'm struggling with is tesseract-orc isn't finding text even in the most simple of images. see my system and version information below:

```
[root@tower python2]# uname -a
Linux tower.youds.com 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 22:03:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@tower python2]# tesseract -v
tesseract 3.02.02
leptonica-1.71
libjpeg 6b : libpng 1.2.52 : zlib 1.2.3
```

The sample images I'm trying work with php ocr class but the or class isn't powerful enough for what I need to do, and apparently tesseract is.

Here's what happens when I run tesseract:

```
[root@tower phpocr]# tesseract W1.png output.file
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
Empty page!!
Empty page!!
[root@tower phpocr]#
```

These are the images I'm using:

http://arbiter.rogues-alliance.com/includes/phpocr/W.png

http://arbiter.rogues-alliance.com/includes/phpocr/W1.png

Edited: included some more images.

Comment: Thanks, I need to get the text from this image, can you help with that? http://arbiter.rogues-alliance.com/includes/phpocr/images/PA_login.php.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `pagesegmode` option, such as `-psm 10` (that is *10 = Treat the image as a single character*), which seems too improve identification for single characters. List the other options with `tesseract --help`.

Unfortunately when I run your example files with `-psm 10` **W.png** and **W1.png** are identified as `w` and `N` respectively, although larger images such as [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Warwick_W_logo.png) correctly identifies as `W`. I would suspect it is the size/font of your sample that causes this. Also, and this is pure speculation, tesseract would likely do a better job identifying this character in context, i.e. along with other characters using the same font and size.

Comment: Thanks, I need to get the text from this image, can you help with that? http://arbiter.rogues-alliance.com/includes/phpocr/images/PA_login.php.png

Comment: That's an image specifically crafted to prevent OCR analysis (writing a spam bot, are we? :D). I suspect you will have a hard time. I'm by no means an OCR expert, but perhaps you'll have better luck using the tesseract library rather than the command line tool.

Comment: I knew you would think that! No, my job is to prove its possible to use tesseract to break the code. So am hoping for some help.

Comment: Haha, just kidding :) I would not argue that it is possible, but wether or not tesseract is the right OCR library I dare not say. I think you will have finer granularity over settings and the process in general using the [Tesseract API](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample) instead, perhaps combined with other image manipulation/analysis tools to identify text and "filter" out the horizontal lines etc. beforehand.

Comment: OK so i followed your advice and paid for ABBYYs services to do the job. They came back with this: http://imgur.com/J2vnzDd which produced "96 TMENTYONE , „  
 3                
" Now I just need to figure out how to do that with tesseract, as I'm sure its possible.